# Boost linking error

Tags: c++, boost, linker

So, I'm trying to use boost.process library. I downloaded package from [this location](http://www.highscore.de/boost/process.zip), copied includes from boost subdirectory into **/usr/include/boost**, wrote a simple code:

```
    namespace bp = ::boost::process;
    std::string execApp = "make";
    std::vector<std::string> args;
    args.push_back("-C ../build");

    bp::context ctx;
    ctx.stdout_behavior = bp::silence_stream();

    bp::child buildProcess = bp::launch(execApp, args, ctx);
```

It compiles but fails at linker:

```
CMakeFiles/DebugConsole.dir/Debug/DebugConsole.cpp.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:208: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_system_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:209: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_generic_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:214: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_generic_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:215: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_generic_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:216: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_system_category()'
CMakeFiles/DebugConsole.dir/Debug/DebugConsole.cpp.o: In function `boost::process::detail::file_handle::posix_remap(int)':
/usr/include/boost/process/detail/file_handle.hpp:264: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_system_category()'
/usr/include/boost/process/detail/file_handle.hpp:269: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_system_category()'
CMakeFiles/DebugConsole.dir/Debug/DebugConsole.cpp.o: In function `boost::process::detail::file_handle::posix_dup(int, int)':
/usr/include/boost/process/detail/file_handle.hpp:295: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_system_category()'
CMakeFiles/DebugConsole.dir/Debug/DebugConsole.cpp.o: In function `pipe':
/usr/include/boost/process/detail/pipe.hpp:86: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_system_category()'
CMakeFiles/DebugConsole.dir/Debug/DebugConsole.cpp.o:/usr/include/boost/process/detail/posix_ops.hpp:202: more undefined references to `boost::system::get_system_category()' follow
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've linked such libraries: `filesystem system date_time`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to see the last answer [**here.**](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=897996)

> I had a very similar problem and found this post while searching. I
>   managed to solved the problem after much more searching, so I post it
>   here for other people.
>
> I had to link to the proper library this way: g++ boost_example.cpp -o
>   run -lboost_filesystem-mt http://linux.overshoot.tv/ticket/127
>
> The real problem is that the boost documentation is lacking and does
>   not say which library to link to. See:
>   http://linux.overshoot.tv/ticket/129
>
> Anyway, to use boost/file_system, link to: -lboost_filesystem-mt .
>
> See also: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=244593